# I want to do something like when someone presses a button the bot waits for a response in text of a mentioned channel in discord.js v14

Tags: discord.js, discord-buttons

actually I am making an announcement command with embeds and modals I did all the work after submitting the modal the bot does send an embed message preview your text embed and button with text send I want it so that after the user presses the button it asks what channel do you want to send the announcement to and waits for a text message response that has the channel mention. so can you please tell how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

**What you are looking for:**
A way so when a user pressed a button a response comes that asks what channel the user wants to send announcement(x) to and then wait.

**Recommended approach**
Use the following guide:

https://discordjs.guide/interactions/buttons.html#building-and-sending-buttons

... and learn how to send buttons for discord.js v14.

After doing so you would want a

> interaction.reply({ content: 'What channel would you like to send your announcement in?'});

line with an await function waiting for the user to send a second message i.e. #announcements-channel (message)

The bot would need to have an array of all the possible channel IDs which you can get by right clicking on a channel and selecting Copy ID (here is a photo)

[image: Example Channel ID image]

Then the bot will get the (message) and send it in #announcements-channel using the channel ID and finish the command.